# Best multiformat C++ mobile development solution?

Tags: iphone, c++, android, mobile

We are thinking about developing some programs and games for Android and iPhone. Everyone involved have most experience working with C++ and OpenGL for games. I found [BatteryTech](http://www.batterypoweredgames.com/batterytech) and [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com). Have anyone tried these and/or any other soultion and has some cons/pros to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm porting a network protocol library to [Airplay SDK](http://airplaysdk.com), you may want to look at it. I'm aware of a few "big names" using it to develop iOS/Android games (due to NDA I'm not able to disclose the names).

The APIs provided are quite OK (there were a few bugs in the sockets API in the past). The tools are a bit crude, but once you setup the project it's more or less acceptable. Unfortunately, I've no experience with Airplay's 3D APIs, you'll need to check it yourself.

The list of target platforms is impressive - iOS, Android, Bada, Symbian, Windows Mobile. You can use Mac & XCode or Windows & Visual Studio for development.

Note, that this is a commercial toolkit, but there's a free evaluation version. I think you should try it yourself!

Comment: AirplaySDK has changed it's name to Marmalade.  They pulled a fast one with their licensing terms - not honouring licenses before the change of name.  There's no free unlimited-time evaluation license any more.  They've hoisted up the prices.  Lots of disgruntled developers are leaving it now.

Comment: Yeah, I've just returned from a short holiday break just to realize what they did :)